# How to summate elements of a 2d-array based on labels using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I'm trying to find a pythonic/numpy way to summate 2d datapoints based on the labels they were given.

Given the following data matrix `X`:

```py
X = np.array(
    [
        [6, 1], # row_0
        [4, 4], # row_1
        [8, 4], # row_2
        [6, 3], # row_..
        [5, 8],
        [7, 9]  # row_5
    ]
)
```

And the labels assigned to it:

```py
labels = np.array([1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
```

It means that `row_0` is assigned the label 1, `row_1` label 0, `row_2`: 2 etc.

Right now i'm trying to summate every datapoint per label using the following loop:

```py
cum_sum = np.zeros((3, 2))
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    cum_sum[label] += X[i]
```

Which results in the following matrix

```
[[11. 13.]
 [12.  4.]
 [13. 12.]]
```

However i was wondering if there was a more pythonic/efficient way to solve this question.
It has been done using 1D arrays [as shown in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606041/cumulative-summation-of-a-numpy-array-by-index).

How would one solve this?

Thanks in advance!

If the question was unclear, please comment.

Comment: `np.bincount((labels[:,None] + [0, np.max(labels)+1]).ravel(), X.ravel()).reshape(-1, 2, order='F')`, I doubt this is faster for large arrays.

Comment: Only ~100x faster for the example data *1000. I suspect `numba` to be much faster.